# How to create an animated background with animation on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scroll

I'm doing some research on how to create an animated background with scroll.

I found this plugin http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/ where it allows me to animate an existing element such as a flat background or simple fonts and geometries that solely constructed from CSS.

But what I wanted to achieve is something like the apple website http://www.apple.com/my/iphone-6s/, their animation is far more sleeker than just a normal 2D animation.

I deduce that they are animating the playback from a video which act as background on scroll..... is that even possible?